# didEnterRegion in iOS 8 - Region Monitoring

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am writing a prototype type for Region monitoring. Below is my set of code

```
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];//commented for iOS 7
```

Thats how I create locationManager

In plist,

```
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Location is required to find out where you are</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Location is required to find out where you are</string>
```

Then

```
-(BOOL) checkLocationManager
    {
        if(![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
        {
            [self showMessage:@"You need to enable Location Services"];
            return  FALSE;
        }
        if(![CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLRegion class]])
        {
            [self showMessage:@"Region monitoring is not available for this Class"];
                    return  FALSE;
        }
        if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied ||
           [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted  )
        {
            [self showMessage:@"You need to authorize Location Services for the APP"];
            return  FALSE;
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
```

I am checking for those conditions

```
-(void) addGeofence:(NSDictionary*) dict
{

    CLRegion * region = [self dictToRegion:dict];
    [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
}
- (CLRegion*)dictToRegion:(NSDictionary*)dictionary
{
    NSString *identifier = [dictionary valueForKey:@"identifier"];
    CLLocationDegrees latitude = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    CLLocationDegrees longitude =[[dictionary valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
    CLLocationDistance regionRadius = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"radius"] doubleValue];

    if(regionRadius > locationManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance)
    {
        regionRadius = locationManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance;
    }

    NSString *version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    CLRegion * region =nil;

    if([version floatValue] >= 7.0f) //for iOS7
    {
        region =  [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:centerCoordinate
                                                   radius:regionRadius
                                               identifier:identifier];
    }
    else // iOS 7 below
    {
        region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:centerCoordinate
                                                       radius:regionRadius
                                                   identifier:identifier];
    }
    return  region;
}
```

This set of code works perfectly on iOS 7.

But when I run the same in iOS 8, when I start monitoring, the delegate method `didStartMonitoringForRegion` is getting called. But `didEnterRegion` is never called when I enter the region.

Is there anything that I should take extra care for iOS 8?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Geofencing didEnterRegion,didExitRegion function not Calling in iphone 5S iOS8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27521220/geofencing-didenterregion-didexitregion-function-not-calling-in-iphone-5s-ios8-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Region monitoring requires *Always* authorization from user. That's new for iOS8.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS8 in addition of the code

```
 [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

and add a key named "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" to plist with a message to be displayed in the prompt, to location when in foreground。

you also have to add this code

```
 [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

after

```
[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

Comment: That is already added. In my question also I have shared my plist

Comment: Have you added this code  [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; after  [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]; If not ,try it.

Comment: Yes. startUpdatingLocation was also already added and the corresponding delegates are getting called.